# Yet another telnet to 25 on AWS EC2 not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, sendmail, telnet

I went through all these error questions that I could find on SO and I've done everything that it appears I should do. Still, I get connection refused when I telnet to port 25

This is what is asked for in other questions:

```
netstat-an | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53045               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::443                      :::*                        LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::52266                    :::*                        LISTEN
```

So, port 25 is listening. Next, can I telnet to 25 on localhost? Yes. No problem. I can do localhost and I can do it with 127.0.0.1 and I can do it with the proper IP address. As long as I am on the machine itself, I can telnet to port 25.

Next, the EC2 firewall. There are two levels, iptables and the EC2 security zone. I made sure iptables and ip6tables were shut down. Service shows that both are "Firewall is not running". I checked the EC2 security zone. It shows:

```
25  tcp  0.0.0.0/0
```

So, it is allowing all traffic to port 25.

Still, I get connection refused when I telnet to port 25.

I continued. I checked /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny. Both are empty.

I continued. I looked in the mail folder. The domain is in local-host-names (which doesn't matter since I never get to the point of entering a recipient email address). I don't see anything about blocking or allowing hosts. Perhaps there is something buried in the cryptic sendmail.cf file. So, I wanted to ensure that sendmail was definitely listening with

```
lsof -i :25
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sendmail 11457 root    4u  IPv4 830292      0t0  TCP *:smtp (LISTEN)
```

Same as netstat. Listening on all devices on port smtp (25).

So, I am at a loss. Why would I get connection refused on port 25? It isn't unable to reach server. It isn't that it is not listening. It is clearly that it is listening and refusing connections.

Comment: Does `telnet test.smtp.org 25` work (it might be that ISP on the client side is blocking port 25)?

Comment: @dusan.bajic Outbound 25 is blocked at some clients. That is why I tried from multiple clients. I've been able to prove to an Amazon support person that nothing is showing up in the server logs. I wrote a program that listens on port 25 and prints the remote IP to a log file when it connects and then disconnects.

Comment: I found the problem and I can leave this question here if others think that it is a good solution for others to see. Otherwise, I can delete the question if it looks like garbage...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that there are two issues:

1) Many ISPs block outbound port 25 requests. So, it is rather common that `telnet somedomain.com 25` will fail and report something like "denied" or "unreachable."

2) Proper programs that go out on port 25 are mail programs. A mail program is designed to send email to your email service, which then uses the MX record for the domain name to deliver the email. What I found is that when you register a domain name with Network Solutions and set "All" IP addresses to be a certain address, they do NOT set the MX record address. That remains set to Network Solutions' mail server. So, if someone uses a proper email program to hit your domain name, it will go to mx.yourdomain.com, which may not be your server.

In my case, I had to manually set the IP address for the mx record with Network Solutions. Then, I magically started getting emails.

For those that don't know how to check MX records, in Linux, you can run `dig domain.name MX`. However, it isn't your MX record setting that matters. It is your mail server's setting. For example, if my computer says the mx record is 12.34.56.78 and I use GMail and Google says the mx record is p.ctmail.com, then sending email through GMail will fail.